# New "From Name" causes an undelivered SMS status in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

We have set up a new journey to do test sends from a Data Extension.

The journey is quite straight that it will trigger all records in the DE with SMS messages once the journey is activated.

We have experienced that when we set a new masked name for the SMS send (set a new "From Name" in the Message Configuration), then all recipients will not receive the SMS messages and SMS send status will be "undelivered"

Here is what I configured in the SMS send

[image]

When I check in:

- All Contact list >> Engagement -> result: "undelivered"
- SMS Analytics in Journey Builder: Deliver rate 0%
- Check in data view:

```SQL
SELECT 
MobileMessageTrackingID,
Mobile,
FromName,
Sent,
Delivered,
Undelivered,
SMSStandardStatusCodeID,
Description,
MessageID, 
CodeID, 
ConversationID, 
CreateDateTime, 
ModifiedDateTime, 
ActionDateTime, 
MessageText, 
SendID, 
Name
FROM _smsmessagetracking s
JOIN _JourneyActivity ja
ON s.Name = ja.activityname
JOIN [_Journey] j
on ja.VersionID = j.VersionID
WHERE j.JourneyName = 'Journey name'
and j.VersionNumber = 'Journey version num'
```

-> Only records with the new "From Name" have Undelivered = true, SMSStandardStatusCodeID = 2500, Description = "Message was not delivered to aggregator"

Anyone have an idea why this error happened and how to solve it? I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: what country are you sending to?

Comment: @EazyE Singapore.. and I'm sure the old "From Name" is working since I tried both the new and the old one

Comment: Have you registered the new from name with the account team and SFMC? this country requires from name registration

Comment: @EazyE I think I will wait for my account team get back to me first, but I feel like you are right

Comment: @EazyE SFMC just confirmed to me that Singapore does require the From Name registration. The account team already registered them before, but somehow the Aggregator didn't put it them the whitelisting, it was solved now. In case, you want to put the answer, I would happily accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending to Singapore requires registering FROM ALPHA ID, you need to reach out to your account team to fill out the necessary paperwork to register each sending name